# Javascript / jQuery: How to make a slider slide in a curved path (iPad's slide to unlock style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am creating iPad's Slide to Unlock using JavaScript and jQuery, but rather than simply going from left to right, it should go same direction, but go round in a circular curve (but not a circle). Could anyone suggest me any ideas how to achieve this? Couldn't find anything in terms of using JavaScript.

Basically, I want to be able to drag my slider in this curve, starting from the bottom and going to the right, then up, and then down again:

[image]

What I already tried is a jQuery Pathslider It does almost what I need, but is a bit jumpy, which doesn't look nice.

Also, examples such as this using SVG, but **I don't need to let user jump to other position without going through whole thing (like on SLIDE TO UNLOCK on iOS)**
http://bseth99.github.io/projects/svg/4-raphael-svg-slider.html

Thanks

Comment: Nice idea, but you need to show what you have tried. Any markup at all?

Comment: I've expanded my post a bit. I am still implementing, and because I wasn't able to find anything useful that would work, I haven't got anything to show. Just added information on what I tried (but didn't work).

Comment: "I am creating" and "I already tried a plugin" - That's pure creativeness... Howsoever, here are some helpful terms to search for: *magnitude*, *dot product*, *cubic/quadratic bezier*, *perpendicular projection*, *interpolation*.